# How to run a 'greater than' query in Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a primary key in the table as 'OrderID', and it's numerical which increments for every new item. An example table would look like -

[image: Sample Table]

---

Let's assume that I want to get all orders above the `OrderID` '`1002`'. How would I do that?
Is there any possibility of doing this with DynamoDB Query?

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact query pattern you need. I didn't get why would you query like this? whats the use case?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with this base table you cannot perform a query with a greater than for the partition key.

You have 3 choices:

- Migrate to using [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), this will use up your read credits significantly.
- Creating a [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html), you'd want a global secondary index with the sort key becoming your order id. Take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating.
- Loop over in the application performing a Query or GetItem request from intial value until there are no results left (very inefficient).

The best practice would be to use the GSI if you can as this will be the most performant.

Comment: Second option is the efficient one and seems like the right approach here. Not sure what you mean by "require rebuild", but adding/removing secondary indices can be easily done without downtime in DynamoDB now.

Comment: Thanks, @mokugo for the answer! But I have one question, why can't I query with that table? And how would I create a secondary index? Also, in other words, does secondary index mean another primary key - which can perform all the operations we can do with the primary key? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, so a query is against a specific partition key. The partition key is the order id from what I see, therefore it is not possible to get more than one partition in a single query. A GSI is comparable to a duplicate table that is kept in sync. You rearrange a different partition key that all orders would share then set the range key to be the order id. Then you can query your GSI and use a greater than condition for the sort key (whilst referencing the partition key).